# How to match strings using Regex

Tags: regex

I have this:

```
https://lh5.ggpht.com/-05ne7Y9Dlog/Xyiy88vo_gI/AAAAAAAAHV4/EwmlTE7FiDonC_lh6Z-UrAtZz_39zRo3QCLcBGAsYHQ/w400-h270/1.png

https://lh5.ggpht.com/-x5hXwqku5es/XyjF5x9Q_jI/AAAAAAAAHWw/F4ayROJynrwKd1H699eu4Ji0yEfayS_RwCLcBGAsYHQ/w171-h200/3.png

https://lh5.ggpht.com/-lWHlL8F0FJo/XyiuolbZWwI/AAAAAAAAHVA/-fOvqyq2rTUxZI2Vxg0op5NwZjg-Apz9QCLcBGAsYHQ/w856-h1000/3.png
```

And i want to match strings like "w400-h270", "w171-h200", "w856-h1000"... Anyone can help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: I try use .+\/\/.+\/.+\/.+\/.+\/.+\/(.+)\/.+ but i think it is not optimize

Answer (score 1):

```
(w\d+-h\d+)
```

Then extract the contents by group(1)